# Error when running npm start from PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, npm, phpstorm

I can run `npm start` without issues from Windows' command prompt but I get [errors](https://hastebin.com/wuzayuqise.tex) instead when using the PhpStorm Terminal.

Are they actually different things or is it some kind of other issue ex. charset?

Comment: You must Install and enable the NodeJS plugin

Comment: I indeed tried to set up `npm start` (http://imgur.com/a/9ceLV) under the `Run` menu but I must be doing something wrong since the same error pops up

Comment: very strange... Error indicates that you have an invalid character ('REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)?) in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\package.json`. I don't think this issue has any relation to PhpStorm...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is must be different shells.
Short answer: in the Settings dialog box find Terminal and specify desired shell.
See more here - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html#d538047e55

Comment: I tried directly setting the path to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and playing around with the Terminal's settings in PHPStorm but it sadly doesn't seem to help